# How to copy the other Unselected items from a listBox to another

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How to copy selected items from ListBox1 to listBox2, and unselected Items to listBox3.
I already know how to copy selected items as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
  { listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItems[i]);}
```

But I don't know how to copy the other unselected items from the main ListBox1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GetSelected(x)` method of Listbox to determine if it is selected to not, and then put it into the appropriate ListBox.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{    
    if (listBox1.GetSelected(i))
        listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i]);
    else
        listBox3.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i]);
}
```

Comment: pls, How to do it without GetSelected ?

Comment: I did it well as below:
 for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                listBox3.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; j++)
            {

                listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItems[j]);
                listBox3.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[j]);

            }